# Sorting Database Table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have a page on an application that allows an administrator to view tables in the database. The section that prints the values is below:

```
<table>
                <?php
                    while ( $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM) ) 
                        {
                        // build table to display results
                        print( "<tr>" );

                        foreach ( $row as $value )          
                        print( "<td>$value</td>" );
                        print( "</tr>" );
                        } 

                     ?>
                </table>
```

This particular table is populated with the names of certain kids, ages, addresses, contact numbers, etc.

I need to enhance this table by sorting both by age and alphabetically (separately).

Keeping efficiency in mind, how can I modify the while loop above to sort the printed data?

Note: The specified table contains no more than 300 results.

Comment: Do you want to sort them on runtime or do you want to receive an already sorted data?

Comment: That code is no use to us. Where is the query. Its normally simpler to use `ORDER BY` in the query than sorting arrays in PHP

Answer (score 1):

why dont you make two queries?

```
Select * from table order by age
```

and

```
Select * from table order by name
```

seems efficient to me!